# Which city is this?

Tags: riddle

Two watchers on two sides of a creek

They are jailing a big dark lake

Three hooks seal the ancient mouth

Keep the east in west and north in south

Comment: Is [tag:knowledge] applicable here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Istanbul?

Two watchers on two sides of a creek

> Istanbul is located on both sides of the Bosphorus Strait.

They are jailing a big dark lake

> Istanbul controls the entrance to the Black Sea.

Three hooks seal the ancient mouth

> There are three bridges across the Bosphorus Strait.

Keep the east in west and north in south

> Constantinople has historically been an important point of connection between Western and Eastern civilisations, and between Russia and the Middle East.

Comment: Congratz! Every single analysis is correct.

Comment: I was thinking of Istanbul too but the none of the lines seemed correct to me. Seems I was wrong. Congrats!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of this answer -

Could the city be

> Aswan?

Two watchers on two sides of a creek

> Possibly the Aswan dam (although why the Nile would be called a creek is beyond me).

They are jailing a big dark lake

> Lake Nasser?

Three hooks seal the ancient mouth

> ????

Keep the east in west and north in south

> The Nile flows from south to north. So the ancient Egyptians thought that up(N) was down(S) (on the map). Therefore, E would be W.

Comment: A good approach right there, but it's not the answer! Of course, "creek" in the riddle is used symbolically.